# Task Manager process list shows multiple abnormalities, processes out of place

Tags: process, task-manager

First, it's not the issue about so many instances of Google Chrome in the process list in the task manager. I consider myself pretty clueful, so technical answers are welcome. Drilling down into the list of processes under Google Chrome in Task Manager, a Malwarebytes Native Message Service process and a Windows Command Processor appear in line among the list of Google Chrome process instances. There are also separate Google Chrome processes that appear after other processes in the process list. I don't have more than one instance of Google Chrome open. Why would those processes that seem to have nothing to do with Google Chrome appear among Google Chrome processes? Why would I have Google Chrome appear as two other processes by themselves way down the list and not under the other Google Chrome process where the multiple Google Chrome and other processes are listed? It seems very unusual.

Comment: Not happening here.  Have you tried sort the TM list?  Arrow at the top of the tab.  13 or 14 chrome processes.

Comment: Chrome (and every other browser, too) have been running as multiple processes for many years.

Comment: At least one process per tab, plus extensions.